# How to break line in the long glossary-extra name entry

Tags: glossaries-extra

I would like to break line in the glossary entry name, in the example below:

Especially to break line in the:

```
likvidatsiya posledstviy primeneniya protivnikom oruzhiya %at this position% massovogo porazheniya
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=altlisthypergroup]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{likvidatsiya-posledstviy-primeneniya-protivnikom-oruzhiya-massovogo-porazheniya}{%
    name={likvidatsiya posledstviy primeneniya protivnikom oruzhiya massovogo porazheniya},%
    description={Eliminating the effects of enemy use of weapons of mass destruction (decontamination) - the aggregate of measures taken to clear up the effects of enemy use of nuclear, biological, and chemical warfare. This is done to restore, in a short period, the disrupted combat efficiency of friendly troops, and to create conditions permitting successful completion of the missions assigned to them.%
    }
}

\begin{document}
    water is good but \gls{likvidatsiya-posledstviy-primeneniya-protivnikom-oruzhiya-massovogo-porazheniya} is better
    
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add `\makeglossaries` to the MWE to  make it compilable

Answer (score 0):

To break  the entry name line we need to insert a `\\`.

Previously  the entry name must be encapsulated in a `parbox` and new style, based on `altlisthypergroup`, defined.

**Before** (the MWE needs `\makeglossaries` added in order to compile)

[image: b]

**After**

[image: b]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newglossaryentry{likvidatsiya-posledstviy-primeneniya-protivnikom-oruzhiya-massovogo-porazheniya}{%
    name={likvidatsiya posledstviy primeneniya protivnikom oruzhiya \\ massovogo porazheniya},%
    description={Eliminating the effects of enemy use of weapons of mass destruction (decontamination) - the aggregate of measures taken to clear up the effects of enemy use of nuclear, biological, and chemical warfare. This is done to restore, in a short period, the disrupted combat efficiency of friendly troops, and to create conditions permitting successful completion of the missions assigned to them.%
    } % \\ inserted 
}

\newglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup2}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}
    {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\glossentryname{##1}}}] 
    \mbox{}\par\nobreak
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}

\glossarystyle{altlisthypergroup2} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

water is good but \gls{likvidatsiya-posledstviy-primeneniya-protivnikom-oruzhiya-massovogo-porazheniya} is better
    
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```